# Creating custom React hook to store File(s) (push/ purge), doesn't render component where it is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-dropzone

I've a create-react-app project with custom hook like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
const useStagedUploads = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState<CustomFileWithPath[]>([]);
    const setUploadItems = (files: CustomFileWithPath[]) => setItems(files);

    return [items, setUploadItems] as const;
};

export default useStagedUploads;
```

I use it to push files to when browsed (using react-dropzone). Now in one of my other component, I use it like below *:

```
const [ items, setUploadItems ] = useStagedUploads();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (items) {
            onDrop(items);
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
            items.map((i) =>
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
                setUploadItems(
                    items.filter(
                        (items: CustomFileWithPath) => items.path !== i.path
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }, [items]);
```

Now when upload is made like so (react-dropzone):

```
const { getInputProps, open, acceptedFiles } = useDropzone({
        noClick: true,
        noKeyboard: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (acceptedFiles) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
            acceptedFiles.map((el) => stageUpload(el));
        }
    }, [acceptedFiles]);
```

... The former component (*) doesn't re-render (tried console, debugger, etc.) ie I don't receive items its empty "`[]`" array. Also doesn't react `useEffect` body.

Gave a try using simple primitive type it does re-render. Is it so that files couldn't be stored in react custom hooks or prevents re-render/ any serialization problem?

Thanks.

Edit:

As requested in comments,
here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-w7swmv?embed=1&file=receive-files.ts

Comment: Perhaps the problem might be that the same array is always returned. Usually, when dealing with arrays in react state(s), you make a shallow copy of them, so try: `setItems([...files])` in `setUploadItems` instead.

Comment: Just gave it a try, no luck. But I'm keeping the spread operator as it seems correct way to update. It is strange that component receives the added files (items array) right after some other operation triggers re-render.

Comment: I'm honestly confused, imho it sounds like there is something else wrong somewhere else. Is it possible for you to create a minimal reproducible example on stackblitz or similar services?

Comment: Alright will do.

Comment: @briosheje Please find the link in question (edited).

Comment: Oh I get it. You are using the hook in the wrong way, assuming that it will have a single store. To do this, you need to create a Context and use a Context with the hook (in order to share the state). Remember that states are not singleton by design, hence if you import the hook twice, it will have two distinct states. Read more about Context here: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @briosheje Alright man, going to dig it up. I hope context will help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You have to create a context and use the context in your hook, then wrap the context provider on top of the components that uses it (you might want to bring it as the wrapper component of the app for instance)